# Kotlin. Strike text and copy it to a clipboard

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning kotlin and trying to make an app that strikes text and copies it to a clipboard

I've already managed to strike text and insert it to a clipboard, however when I open keyboard to paste it, it appears like normal text. When I longpress the text field and tap 'paste' it pastes as intended.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                strokedText.text = null
                val a = textInput.text.toString()
                val spannableString1 = SpannableString(a)
                spannableString1.setSpan(StrikethroughSpan(), 0, a.length, 0)
                strokedText.text.replace(0,0, spannableString1)
            }
        })


    }

    fun convert(view: View) {
        super.moveTaskToBack(true)
        val clipboard: ClipboardManager =
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager

        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", strokedText.text)

        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
        textInput.text = null
        //Toast.makeText(this, "All Done! Past your text now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.copyMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//        minimizeApp()
        }
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on  "when I open keyboard to paste it, it appears like normal text"? Do you mean clipboard functionality of whatever keyboard app your using? Because in that case there's nothing you can do if it choses to drop formatting.

Comment: I'm using Google keyboard. When I tap on edit text to paste my text, it offers unformatted text like 'Hello, World!'. When I long tap the box and context menu shows (copy, cut, paste etc), the words are stroke. (like  ̶H̶e̶l̶l̶o̶,̶ ̶W̶o̶r̶l̶d̶!̶). I tried to download different apps from G.Play and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find the solution by adding the Unicode symbol "\u0336"

```
fun convert(view: View) {
        super.moveTaskToBack(true)
        val clipboard: ClipboardManager =
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager

        for (asd in strokedText.editableText.length downTo 0) {
            strokedText.editableText.insert(asd, "\u0336")
        }
        val clip = ClipData.newHtmlText("",strokedText.text,("<del>" + strokedText.editableText+ "</del>"))
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
        textInput.text = null
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.copyMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

I made ClipData as HtmlText, but I'm pretty sure that PlainText will also work.

Now, clipboard offers well struck text instead of original one